# Possible typo in a text using Fourier transform properties

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

I am working my way carefully through an [article in Analytical Chemistry](https://doi.org/10.1021/ac50057a033) on round-off error. I'm a scientist but not a professional mathematician so it is rather slow-reading for me and none of it is *intuitively* obvious. The article is frustrating to read because there are numerous typographical errors that temporarily stop me in my tracks before I can convince myself that they are indeed errors. More problematic are the occasions when I'm unsure whether I have encountered a typo or simply failed to understand something. Hence the following ...

At one point in the article, a formula is stated and the derivation of the formula is said to rely on *three general properties of characteristic functions*. The verbatim statement of the third such property is:

> If $g(t)$ is the characteristic function of $f(z)$, then the characteristic function of $\int_{-\infty}^{z} f(z) \  dz$ is $-g(t)/it$

where $i = \sqrt{-1}$.

I assume that the  denominator for $-g(t)$  is intended to be the whole of $i \times t$ (am I correct?) ... but I don't understand what is going on with $z$ being the apparent limit of the integral as well as being the variable of integration? Is there a typo, and if so, what should the formula say ... or have I misunderstood something?  ... If the limit of integration can really be the same as the variable of integration, then what should I read to understand what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is most likely a typo, as you can see since they are using $t$ on the right of your equation. It should rather be
$$
\int_{-\infty}^t f(z)\,\mathrm d z = -\,g(t)/(it).
$$

**After edit:**
Then it should rather be
"the characteristic function of $\int_{-\infty}^z f(w)\,\mathrm dw$ is $-g(t)/(it)$", or any other variable name different from $z$. It is true that the abuse of notation of using the same variable inside and outside the integral is sometimes made. It is however as you noticed ambiguous.

Comment: I have made a critical error in my typing, for which I sincerely apologise. the '=' sign should have been the word 'is'. That is, the assertion is that if the c.f. of f(z) is g(t) then the c.f. of the strange integral IS -g(t)/(i*t). It makes all the difference because the 't' appears as a result of the fourier transform using exp(i z t), and probably not, as you have suggested, as the result of it being the limit of the integration. I have corrected my post. My apologies once again.

Comment: No problem, I added a corresponding change to the answer